# Ajax load more for search engine bots

Tags: seo, ajax

On my website I am only displaying 20 posts for visitors, when they scroll down it loads more. I want to know if will affect the ranking of my website in a negative way if I load, for example, 100 posts for search engines.

I am not worried much about the loading time as I am loading only text (really small posts). I would really appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to do this, because it is good accessibility, is to have your page load showing the 20 posts you normally show. Under it have a link to show more which takes you to a page showing more results. This makes your content available to *everybody*. No JavaScript required.

Then use JavaScript to remove the link to show more posts when the DOM loads but before the document displays. Then have your code add more posts as a user scrolls as normal.

Good accessibility/SEO and good user experience. Win-win.